# C# Exclude Threads from Debugger to prevent them being suspended

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, callback, hook

I've got the following code:
https://github.com/YatoDev/Yato.LowLevelInput/blob/master/Yato.LowLevelInput/WindowsHooks/WindowsHook.cs

I am using this for LowLevelMouse and LowLevelKeyboard hooks.

When i debug the application and pause it, the hook wont execute.
This results in input lags for at least 10 seconds

I also tested it using CreateThread instead of a managed thread (also with the HideFromDebugger flag)
Sadly, it does not help.

It seems like the c# debugger freezes any thread that executes managed code.

I wonder if there is a way to exclude my hook threads to prevent them being suspended.

Note: I searched for this problem but i did not find an answer providing an automated solution. I hope to find a way to exclude them by Thread.Name.Contains("Foo") or by setting up the debugger to never suspend all threads.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I checked out the Windows hook class, looks pretty standard. When you say *debug the application and pause it, the hook won't execute* is that because the hooks were setup on the target app/process and when you're in the Visual Studio process debugging they are not called.

Comment: if the thread where the hook is created (see, it needs a message loop and needs to be alive) is suspended then windows calling the Hook ends up in a "timeout" which may causes the hook to being not called anymore. Also this is very annoying while debugging. because mouse and keyboard will stop to work until windows timeouts the hook